# PDO/MySQL - unable to use parameter for column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to search my table based on user input for 1) searchtype and 2) query. searchtype will be the column selected (so searching by name, rating, location etc.)

My code is:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=assignment','admin', 'puppies');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `profs` WHERE :searchtype LIKE :query');
    $result->bindValue(':searchtype', $_GET['searchtype']);
    $result->bindValue(':query', "%" . $_GET['query'] . "%");
    $result->execute();
    $result->debugDumpParams();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($result as $record) {
        echo "<tr><td>", $record['name'], '</td>';
        echo "<td>", $record['school'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $record['subject'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $record['latitude'], ",", $record['longitude'], "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

I know for sure that the problem is with searchtype. If I directly replace :searchtype with `name` in the prepare statement, my code works as planned. In the bindValue statement, I've even directly replaced  $_GET['searchtype'] with `name`, '"' . `name` . '"', and every other permutation I can think of.

Comment: Column names cannot be binded. Over.

Comment: @u_mulder Oh wow my mistake. So do I have to create a switch for each possible searchtype, and then a different PDO query? in my site, searchtype is selected from a dropdown list, so I was never too worried about injection attacks, but I just wanted to use prepared statements as much as possible to avoid it

Comment: It's up to you to decide

Comment: @u_mulder fair point. I'm very new to creating websites. searchtype is selected from a drop-down list. Is there any reason I should fear sql injection from this part, and worry about not binding parameters? Obviously I have to bind query

Comment: Wait, I'll write my asnwer then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, we start with point that binding column names is not allowed. (Table names too, btw).

Going further, I don't think you need `switch`. You can define some whitelist of fields (yes, even if you have fields via `select` it is still vulnerable, cause I can change your `<select>` to my `<input>` with same name).

So, use a whiltelist, some basic code is:

```
$allowed_fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];  // whitelist here
if (in_array($_GET['searchtype'], $allowed_fields)) {
    $result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `profs` WHERE ' . $_GET['searchtype'] . ' LIKE :query');
    $result->bindValue(':query', "%" . $_GET['query'] . "%");
    $result->execute();
    $result->debugDumpParams();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks! I didn't know that I could put my $_GET into the SQL query like that

Comment: You can, but it should be done __very carefully__. For binding `values` the only option is still prepared staements.

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind column name
And it is bad idea to $_GET column name, use `switch`

Comment: Ah... Well now I'm conflicted. It seemed like a really convenient idea. Even with the whitelist approach, is it still not safe?

Comment: And it is also safe